# Changing image property upon button press

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, properties, uiimage

i have a UIImageView displayed in my view with an image "image1" already set.

I have a button below it.

During runtime i would like the image to change to "image 2" when the button is pressed and upon release i would like the image to display "image1" again

1) I know that i have to give the UIImage a label or something so that i can access it from xcode.
2) i know that i need to change the propery of the image upon press
3) i need to have an IBAction or something so that when i press the button it should change the property of the image to "image2"

BUT i dont know how to do this?

Can someone help please?

Comment: I added the "cocoa" tag because that's what this is. Please don't roll it back, it belongs here.

Comment: A few questions: are your image and button created in interface builder, or in code?
Which step if the things do you not know how to do? All three?
Do you have a view controller for the view with the image and the button? (If your view is in interface builder, it is usually named the same as your view, i.e. YourView.m)

Comment: the image and button is created in interface builder. I would like to know step 2 and 3, since i know step 1 now thanks to Graham Lee. Yes i have a view controller which contains the view and the image. its called SecondViewController

Comment: skaffman: No, this is Cocoa Touch, not Cocoa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an *outlet* in your controller that is connected to the image view, so that the controller can find and message the image view. Check out [this tutorial](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/iphone-programming-fundamentals-outlets-and-actions), and the [Interface Builder documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/ConnectionsandBindings/ConnectionsandBindings.html).

Comment: Ok so step 1 is done. Referencing. Lee your tutorial helped me.

But how do i access the image property of UIImageView?
For example to access the x and y property in a typical language would be... image.x = 60;
image.setImage = New Image("hello");
for example. How do i first access the image programmatically and then set the image?

Comment: @Pavan from the documentation, set the image property of the view. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/image